# Two events on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I am new in CSS and JS. I am trying to have two events happening on mousehover but It is not wroking. Here is the code I have

```
<div class="ht2_icon ht2left" style="background: url(icons/img4.png) no-repeat center;" onClick="popup('#newTeam')"> 
    <span class="tooltip" onmouseover="tooltip.pop(this, 'New Team', {position:0})"> 
        <img src="icons/img4hover.png"/>
    </span>
</div>
```

I should have the tooltip and the other image working on mouse hover but it is not the case.

Comment: Where is the javascript/jquery?

Comment: Can you give the function names you want to call on mouseover?

Comment: so set onmouseover on the image if i understand what you are looking for. You could use onmouseenter which bubbles

Comment: what are the 2 events? and which event is not working and when? and what do you mean by _ the other image not working_? what should happen to that other
(which?) image?

Comment: the two events are 
When hovering 
1- A tooltip should appear
2- inverse of the image should appear so if the normal image was light grey on hovering it will turn to dark grey

Answer (score 1):

To see other image only on hover please use separate css definition for ht2_icon or ht2left:

```
.ht2left:hover { background: url(icons/img_hover.png) no-repeat center; }
```

For lunching multiple events please use bind (it is tagged jquery so this is jquery solution, but with other frameworks it will be very similar)

```
$( ".ht2left" ).bind( "hover", popup('#newTeam'));
$( ".ht2left" ).bind( "hover", method2('#newTeam'));
```

Comment: What if it is not only one image so that I can't edit it in the CSS ?? like I can't use
    { background: url(icons/img_hover.png) no-repeat center; }

because for every image there is another equivalent img on hovering

Comment: You could add the image to popup as a [`data-*`attribute](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes): ``<div data-popup-image="foo.jpg"></div>`and then access it using jQuery: `$element.data('popup-image')` to change the `src` of the popup `<img>`.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep your HTML, CSS and JavaScript separate and bind your callbacks programmatically. Your "clean" HTML would look like this (I added the class `popup-trigger`):

```
<div class="ht2_icon ht2left popup-trigger"> 
    <span class="tooltip"> 
        <img src="icons/img4hover.png"/>
    </span>
</div>
```

In JavaScript, your can then add multiple event listener to an element, please check [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/27LNr/2/) and the following code:

```
tooltips[i].addEventListener('mouseover', popTooltip);
tooltips[i].addEventListener('mouseover', doSomethingElse);
```

If you are using jQuery, you should use the [.on() function](http://jqapi.com/#p=on), it will execute the callback for all current and future elements that match the selector.

```
var $triggers = $(".popup-triggers");
$triggers.on("click", function() {
    // do something
});
```